# Represent a negative number in any base

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I can't manage to find the procedure to convert a negative decimal number in a number in any base by using the two's complement representation of numbers.

In particular, I would like to do this to solve the following exercise:

> "Write the function itob(n,s,b) that converts the integer n into a
> base b character representation in the string s. In particular,
> itob(n,s,16) formats s as a hexadecimal integer in s. "

Comment: By "negative decimal number" do you mean input from a textual string?

Comment: If the number is negative, add `-` to resulting string and negate the number. Then proceed as usual.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat works good, except for pesky `INT_MIN` as negating that is troublesome.